# Individual silhouette observations from dtwclust

Tags: r, time-series, clustering

I'm working on a project where I'm evaluating different methods to select control stores. One of the methods I'm evaluating is the time series clustering package, dtwclust. I have everything working, and visually it looks like it's doing a good job.
[image: dtwclust using dtw_basic and PAM]

I'd like to further evaluate the validity of the clusters. While dtwclust gives you the average silhouette coefficient using CVI, I'm wondering if there's a way to get the silhouette coefficient for each cluster, or better yet, for each observation (to detect outliers or wrongly placed observations). Does anyone have any recommendations? I've used the package "fpc" to calc clusters si coefficients, but I don't think it's using the distance metric I'm using (dtw_basic) as the results are very low (.05 - .10)

thanks